# Datagridview SelectionChanged event based on row selection

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, datagridview, datagridviewrow

I have a DataGridView on a TabPage. When the user clicks on a row, a second DGV appears. Each row is associated with its own DGV filled with data. What I want is for when the user goes from one row to another, the DataGridView changes too. So far I've tried the SelectionChanged event but I don't want the DGV to reload in the event that the user clicks on a separate cell in the same row. Any help would greatly be appreciated.

```
void dgv1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)           
{    
    int rowIndex = dgv1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Index;

    if (dgv1 == null)
        return;
    if (dgv1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[rowIndex].Selected == true);
    {
        dgv2.Size = new Size(dgv2.Width + 800, dgv2.Height);
        dgv2.Location = new Point(0, 500);   

        tp.Controls.Add(dgv2);

        Console.WriteLine("Row clicked");
    }
}
```

-Tatiana

Comment: Can you create a property that represents the currently selected row, and then check if the newly selected row is the same or not?

Comment: There actually is a property for the currently selected row which is dgv.CurrentRow the problem is how to check for the newly selected row. Secondly, CurrentRow is of type DataGridViewRow which cannot be converted to type int and therefore I get an error when trying to compare it to any int.

Comment: DataGridViewRow has an Index property, so it'd be dgv.CurrentRow.Index. MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow_properties%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: use  e.rowIndex inside rowenter and rowleave.  they trigger when you navigate to a row up or down (doesnt require you to enter in to editing mode of that cell/row )   

**gotcha** if you  use dgv.currentRow  it will give you previous row it may confuse you. be sure to use e.rowIndex that comes from event.

Answer (score 15):

```
    int curRow = -1;

    private void dgv1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dgv1.CurrentRow.Index != curRow)
        {
            curRow = dgvPatientDetail.CurrentRow.Index;        
        }
```

Comment: Or set dgv1.SelectMode = FullRowSelect; Shouldn't fire SelectionChanged when click is within same row

Answer (score 3):

I know the post is old but for others reading:
Setting ..

> DataGridView1.FullRowSelect = true

should resolve this issue.

Comment: Do you mean `dgv1.SelectionMode = FullRowSelect`, which is already mentioned above?